# Firefox not showing span over a div

Tags: html, css, firefox, textbox

am making a text box with a prefix of currency.
i use the following css

```css
    .currencyInput {
         position: relative;
     }
     .currencyInput input {
         /*padding-left:18px;*/
         padding-left: 25px;
     }
     .currencyInput:before {
         position: absolute;
         top: 0;
         content:"Rs";
         left: 5px;
     }
    .text-box1{
     border:1px solid #31BAF9;
     width:-webkit-calc(95% - 11px);
     width:calc(95% - 11px);
     padding:0 5px;
     margin:5px auto;
     height:42px;
    }
```

```html
    <span class="currencyInput">
            <input type="text" class="text-box1" placeholder="Price" value="35750.00"name="price"/>
          </span>
```

this code works good in chrome.
but when it comes to Firefox the span data is not shown.
any idea?!

Comment: Works fine for me in FF. Maybe clear your cache?

Comment: Also working for me in FF (v37.0.1). Please clarify which version of FF you are experiencing this problem in.

Comment: On my machine, the snippet works even better in FF than in Chrome. In Chrome, the Rs and the number are not on the same baseline.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried your code in Firefox and it worked perfectly! Try to update your browser and then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd> to refresh cache. Can you show us a snapshot of what you see in both browsers?

Comment: @AlokRajasukumaran Developer edition, that's an Aurora build, isn't it? As far as I can see, it's an Alfa version of 39.0. Not the same as the regular release. Maybe it has a few bugs to iron out? By the way, as far as I'm aware, those editions have updates about once a day, so if you let it update now, you may find your problem solved.

Comment: Oh, and the tinypic screen shot is not from this snippet, is it?

Comment: @lister., its from the html page am dealing with.
i guess it should be the issue with the aura build.
will cross check now.

Comment: I'm looking at the snippet with the latest SeaMonkey nightly now (Gecko 40.0) and it still looks OK, so I'm not convinced the Gecko version number is to blame. Say, do you have any extensions installed? What happens if you take a look after restarting in Safe Mode?